# Really be confused with .htaccess of mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried two .htaccess files in the same directory. They are different, but both of them can access the same url successfully. What happened? Thanks!

The first .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule da /site1/testin.php [L]                                                                                                                                          
</IfModule>
```

The second .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule da testin.php [L]                                                                                                                                            
</IfModule>
```

I put them in /site1. And the testin.php is in /site1 .
When I visited http://127.0.0.1/site1/da, both of them worked well. Why? There is no testin.php in / . How did the apache find it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your second rule works because you are using a relative target path **testin.php** which maps to your **/site1/** folder. So this  finds the file in /site1 not the root.

Comment: Yes! You are right. I changed testin.php to /testin.php then it didn't work. Thank you so much!